# trying to open iis in windows form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, webforms

I am using below code to start IIS in Windows Form.

```
if (hWndDocked != IntPtr.Zero) //don't do anything if there's already a window docked.
    return;

hWndParent = IntPtr.Zero;

pDocked = Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\inetmgr");
while (hWndDocked == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    pDocked.WaitForInputIdle(1000); //wait for the window to be ready for input;
    pDocked.Refresh();              //update process info
    if (pDocked.HasExited)
    {
        return; //abort if the process finished before we got a handle.
    }
    hWndDocked = pDocked.MainWindowHandle;  //cache the window handle
}
//Windows API call to change the parent of the target window.
//It returns the hWnd of the window's parent prior to this call.
hWndOriginalParent = SetParent(hWndDocked, panel1.Handle);

//Wire up the event to keep the window sized to match the control
panel1.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(Panel1_Resize);
//Perform an initial call to set the size.
Panel1_Resize(new Object(), new EventArgs());
```

But I am getting error:

> the system cannot find the file

But the same thing works for notepad.

Comment: Well, does `"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\inetmgr"` actually exist?

Comment: Yes.  It actually exist.

Comment: Is it possible the program doesn't have permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and the only way I found was this:

```
Process.Start(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\inetsrv\\iis.msc");
```

I hope it helps!